# scrolling animation for elements of certain class using js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a scrolling animation for each element of class `js-scroll`. Inside the style code, I have a class `.scrolled-proj` which changes the opacity of a project from 0 to 1. The js code adds this class to each `js-scroll` element when it appears in the window (within 100 pixels, based on the offset input). Relevant bits of my code are as follows:

```js
const scroll_elem = document.querySelectorAll(".js-scroll");
scroll_elem.forEach( (el) => {el.style.opacity = "0";} );

// returns true if elem is "in view"
const in_view = (el, off) => {
    const top = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    return ( top <= (window.innerHeight - offset) );
}

const scroll_animation = () => {
    scroll_elem.forEach((el) => {
        if(in_view(el, 100)){ el.classList.add("scrolled-proj"); }
        else{ el.classList.remove("scrolled-proj"); }
    })
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => { 
    scroll_animation();
});
```

```css
.project-elem {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    margin: 5rem 5rem;
    --height: 300px;
}

.projects {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3rem;
    background-color: #DDCDE8;
    font: Asap, sans-serif;
    height: 5*var(--height);
    text-align: center;
}

.project-n {
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    padding: 3rem;
}

.img {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 40%;
    height: 250px;
}

.scrolled-proj{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects" id=#projects>
  <h2>My Projects</h2>

  <article class="project-elem">
      <div class="project-n js-scroll" id="dictocounter">
          <h3>Dictation Counter</h3>
          <p>info about proj</p>
          <img src="dictocounter1.jpg" alt="Dictocounter in Action">
      </div>
      <div class="img js-scroll">
          <p>heres SOME IMAGE</p>
      </div>
  </article>

  <article class="project-elem">
      <div class="project-n js-scroll" id="calc">
          <h3>RPN Calculator</h3>
          <p>info about proj</p>
          <img src="calc.jpg" alt="RPN Calculator Decoding Input">
      </div>
      <div class="img js-scroll">
          <p>heres SOME IMAGE</p>
      </div>
  </article>

  <article class="project-elem">
      <div class="project-n js-scroll" id="markov">
          <h3>Markov Chain Text Generation</h3>
          <p>info about proj</p>
          <img src="calc.jpg" alt="Markov Chain Text Generation">
      </div>
      <div class="img js-scroll">
          <p>heres SOME IMAGE</p>
      </div>
  </article>

  <article class="project-elem">
      <div class="project-n js-scroll" id="audio">
          <h3>Song Similarities</h3>
          <p>info about proj</p>
          <img src="calc.jpg" alt="Audio Spectral Analysis">
      </div>
      <div class="img js-scroll">
          <p>heres SOME IMAGE</p>
      </div>
  </article>

  <article class="project-elem">
      <div class="project-n js-scroll" id="tree">
          <h3>DFS/BFS Search Tree</h3>
          <p>info about proj</p>
          <img src="calc.jpg" alt="Simple Trees">
      </div>
      <div class="img js-scroll">
          <p>heres SOME IMAGE</p>
      </div>
  </article>  
</div>
```

Upon refreshing the webpage, each js-scroll element is indeed initialized to opacity 0, but scrolling does not change the opacity of any of the js-scroll elements. As a sanity check, I made the `in_view` function always return true, but all js-scroll elements remained transparent. This seems to suggest that `scroll_animation` is not being called (since `in_view` is not changing the opacity of any elements), but I don't know why this would be the case.

Comment: stack overflow would not let me post this without enclosing the code snippets in \```. Without the \```, the code can be run as normal. If anyone can figure out how to format the code without the ```, please make an edit to the post- thanks!

Comment: it looks like the variable `offset` is not defined within the scope of the function `in_view`. I would also suggest naming the function added to scroll event listener and removing the listener after it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues.

You are passing the ***param*** `off` into the `in_view()` ***function***, however the functions ***return*** statement is referencing `offset` which is ***undefined***.

Then you are placing an *inline* style to the `.js-scroll` elements for an *opacity of 0* using JS in the ***forEach*** loop. That inline style will override the computed style coming fromt he class when it is added, therefor your opacity will never actually be set to **1** regardless of the addition of the class that defines the opacity property to 1.

**TEST:** First fix your parameter naming issue and rename the ***return*** in the `in_view` function to ***`off`***, then you can run your scroll event and then look at the inspector and it will be right there in the inline style attribute, `style="opacity:0;` along with the class,`scrolled-proj` that is supposed to change the opacity to 1.

To fix this create a helper *css rule* that initializes the opacity property using a ***class*** and not an ***inline style*** created with javascript.

So change the `in_view` function to reference the correct param, `off`, then add a CSS class that sets opacity to 0. => a class to the initial loop that iterates over the `.js-scroll` elements like this...

```js
// reference the proper param in your return here
const in_view = (el, off) => {
  const top = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  return (top <= (window.innerHeight - off));
}
```

```css
/* add a helper class that will set your opacity to 0 intially */
.scrolled-proj-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms linear; /* optional .5 second animation for opacity */
```

Then JS

```
// Now instead of inline style, we add the helper class using el.classList.add()
const scroll_elem = document.querySelectorAll(".js-scroll");
scroll_elem.forEach((el) => {
  el.classList.add("scrolled-proj-hidden");
});
```

Then on your `scroll_animation` function set the proper classes in your conditional like this...

```js
const scroll_animation = () => {
  scroll_elem.forEach((el) => {
    if (in_view(el, 100)) {
      el.classList.add("scrolled-proj");
      el.classList.remove("scrolled-proj-hidden");
    } else {
      el.classList.remove("scrolled-proj");
      el.classList.add("scrolled-proj-hidden");
    }
  })
}
```

```js
const scroll_elem = document.querySelectorAll(".js-scroll");
scroll_elem.forEach((el) => {
  el.classList.add("scrolled-proj-hidden");
});

// returns true if elem is "in view"
const in_view = (el, off) => {
  const top = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  return (top <= (window.innerHeight - off));
}

const scroll_animation = () => {
  scroll_elem.forEach((el) => {
    if (in_view(el, 100)) {
      el.classList.add("scrolled-proj");
      el.classList.remove("scrolled-proj-hidden");
    } else {
      el.classList.remove("scrolled-proj");
      el.classList.add("scrolled-proj-hidden");
    }
  })
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", scroll_animation);
```

```css
.project-elem {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  margin: 5rem 5rem;
  --height: 300px;
}

.projects {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3rem;
  background-color: #DDCDE8;
  font: Asap, sans-serif;
  height: 5*var(--height);
  text-align: center;
}

.project-n {
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.img {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 40%;
  height: 250px;
}

.scrolled-proj {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms linear;
}

.scrolled-proj-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects" id=#projects>
  <h2>My Projects</h2>

  <article class="project-elem">
    <div class="project-n js-scroll" id="dictocounter">
      <h3>Dictation Counter</h3>
      <p>info about proj</p>
      <img src="dictocounter1.jpg" alt="Dictocounter in Action">
    </div>
    <div class="img js-scroll">
      <p>heres SOME IMAGE</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="project-elem">
    <div class="project-n js-scroll" id="calc">
      <h3>RPN Calculator</h3>
      <p>info about proj</p>
      <img src="calc.jpg" alt="RPN Calculator Decoding Input">
    </div>
    <div class="img js-scroll">
      <p>heres SOME IMAGE</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="project-elem">
    <div class="project-n js-scroll" id="markov">
      <h3>Markov Chain Text Generation</h3>
      <p>info about proj</p>
      <img src="calc.jpg" alt="Markov Chain Text Generation">
    </div>
    <div class="img js-scroll">
      <p>heres SOME IMAGE</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="project-elem">
    <div class="project-n js-scroll" id="audio">
      <h3>Song Similarities</h3>
      <p>info about proj</p>
      <img src="calc.jpg" alt="Audio Spectral Analysis">
    </div>
    <div class="img js-scroll">
      <p>heres SOME IMAGE</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="project-elem">
    <div class="project-n js-scroll" id="tree">
      <h3>DFS/BFS Search Tree</h3>
      <p>info about proj</p>
      <img src="calc.jpg" alt="Simple Trees">
    </div>
    <div class="img js-scroll">
      <p>heres SOME IMAGE</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

If this is not what you were looking for, let me know and I can edit or delete this answer.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful. Are all styles set in js inline styles, or can non-inline styles be set in js?

Comment: You can target a style sheet and write to it using JS but anytime you use the ***.style*** property it will write to the HTML element attribute as inline styles. You can also target the the style tag that lives in the head of the document and write to it as well. You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information